# Definition of projective space

Tags: projective-space

I am reading Silverman's 'The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves'.
[image]

It says $\mathbb{P}^n(K)=\{[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\in\mathbb{P}^n:\text{ all }x_i\in K\}$, and then a remark says: if $P=[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\in\mathbb{P}^n(K)$, it does not follow that
each $x_i\in K$.

I am confused by the remark because clearly in the definition it says all $x_i\in K$

Comment: The author probably means that the equivalence class must have some representative where all coordinates belongs to $K$. It doesn't mean that **all** representatives satisfy that. So $[x_0,...,x_n]\in\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ means that there is some $0\ne\lambda\in\overline{K}$ such that $\lambda x_0, \lambda x_1,...,\lambda x_n$ all belong to $K$.

Comment: If you want to learn what a projective space is, we could start by taking some special cases before we get into the general definition of Silverman.

Comment: What is $\mathbb A$ in Silverman's definition ? I've never seen such a convoluted definition for such a simple notion

Comment: To follow up on the comment by @Mark here is an example.  If $ K $ is the field of rational numbers, so that $ \bar K $ is (I presume) the field of algebraic complex numbers, then $ [ 0 , \sqrt 2 , 2 \sqrt 2 ] \in \mathbb P ^ 2 ( K ) $, because $ [ 0 , \sqrt 2 , 2 \sqrt 2 ] = [ 0 , 1 , 2 ] $, and $ 0 , 1 , 2 \in K $, even though $ \sqrt 2 , 2 \sqrt 2 \notin K $.  However, if we pick either $ \sqrt 2 $ or $ 2 \sqrt 2 $ (but not $ 0 $) and divide everything by that, then we get a representative with coordinates in $ K $: either $ [ 0 , 1 , 2 ] $ or $ [ 0 , 1 / 2 , 1 ] $.

Comment: By the way, it seems weird (as @StéphaneJaouen noticed) to define $ \mathbb P ^ n ( K ) $ as a subset of $ \mathbb P ^ n ( \bar K ) $, since the definition of $ \mathbb P ^ n ( K ) $ could proceed exactly like the definition of $ \mathbb P ^ n ( \bar K ) $ (which Silverman abbreviates as $ \mathbb P ^ n $) by starting from $ \mathbb A ^ { n + 1 } ( K ) $ instead of $ \mathbb A ^ { n + 1 } ( \bar K ) $ (which I presume is what Silverman means by $ \mathbb A ^ { n + 1 } $).  But I guess it works.